# Problem with media player in some android devices

Tags: java, android, media

I have a media player that I want to play only audio (radio streaming from web radio) and in some devices it can't play. It seems that plays but I can't hear the audio(it doesn't plays audio from speakers).Thanks in advance.

```java
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("radio_url.com");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: "Some" devices does not help much. Do you have any specific data that would help isolate the issue (device API level / manufacturer)?

Comment: I tested it on Samsung galaxy A50 & A70 and on Xiaomi Mi A2 and it can't play audio. In other devices it's ok. Maybe it can play only in older devices, but I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media player does have issues on some specific devices due to hardware config.
You should go for ExoPlayer. it's the best streaming player out there, by Android, the Youtube app uses the same player.
I had used it in many Media Application
It supports all of the media types as well and easy to implement.

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer